# meteor dynamic meta tags

Tags: dynamic, meteor, meta-tags

Well, i need some way to have a dynamic meta tags for my app, im creating a cms-blog so ill need to change the meta desc/keywords/title etc at every post,im using iron-router.
i have an idea how to do so using not completely  sure:

```
<template name="post">
{{metaTitle}}
</template>

Template.post.metaTitle = function (this) {
  document.title = this;
}
```

(iron-router version)

```
this.route('post', {
        path: '/',
....
data: function () {
return Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
}
//Posts holds post documents with a fields like: "metaTitle" "metaKeywords" etc
});
```

so if a client routes to "/" and the Posts collection holds a post with id of "/"
and the document holds metaTitle:"Post 1"
will this proceed to the template.post.metaTitle helper
and the title will be "Post 1"?

is there a better way?

and doing similar stuff to the keywords etc.

Answer (score 0):

ok , i have manged to do this, here is what i'v done:

html:

```
<template name="posts">

    {{metaTitle}}
    {{metaDesc}}
    {{metaKeywords}}

    {{>home}}

    {{#each posts}}
    </div>
    <a href="{{pathFor 'post'}}">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
            <div class="post">
                <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">
                    <h4 class="left">{{author}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="right">{{date}}</h4>
                </div>
                <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                <p>{{desc}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <hr/>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

router (iron-router):

```
this.route('posts', {
        path: '/',

        waitOn:function(){
            NProgress.start();
            Meteor.subscribe("Teams");
        },

        before: function () {
            Session.set("adding_group", false);
            NProgress.done();
            /*
             causes problems when phonegap mode
             */
        },

        fastRender:true,

        unload: function () {
            Session.set("adding_group", true);
            Session.set("group_name", false);
            Session.set("group_date", false);
            Session.set("group_friends", false);
            Session.set("group_location", false);
            Session.set("group_rules", false);
            Session.set("group_desc", false);
            Session.set("group_save", false);
        },
        yieldTemplates: {
            'nav': {to: 'header'}
        },

        data:{
            posts:Posts.find({}),
            metaTitle:function(){
                var one = Posts.findOne({}); //just for the example
                return document.title = one.title; //just for the example
            }
        }
    });
```

this will insert a document.title of the posts if ill do this dynamic path segments
( findOne by ID ) it will return the current post title,
i think ill make this simple thing a package, i haven't seen similar package at atmosphere.
hope it helps you guys.